Windows 11 won't allow login (screen locks when I attempt to login)
I have a Windows 11 PC (Lenovo 82xx laptop) that was setup with a Microsoft Account that I used for Windows login. I forgot the PIN, and attempt to go through the reset process, but did not complete it--I was interrupted.
I came back several days later to attempt to reset the login PIN on the device, but now when I click "I forgot my PIN" on the Windows login screen, it immediately locks the screen--it does not start the password reset process.
I have another user on this same device that is also an Administrative User, so I logged in to that account, removed the account that I couldn't get into (it had no local information I needed), and then re-added it. I was notified that "the first time this user logs in you will need to be connected to the internet."
I restarted the machine, verified I was connected to the internet, and now when I click on the user I'm interested in, and then "Sign in", the screen immediately locks.
I theorize that perhaps the incomplete PIN reset process has gotten this user "wedged" into an inoperable state? Although that's just a theory.
How might I proceed to be able to get logged in with my target Microsoft Account? Perhaps there is a more theory "clean-out" of the account that needs to happen on the device before it can be re-added?
I've already gone the process of changing my Microsoft Account password at https://account.microsoft.com/account/manage-my-account and there is no change in behavior.

Once you deleted the account the unique user was deleted, even if the user was recreated, the user that is created even if it shared a name would have no relation to the original account.  I would try removing the device from your MSA.

Salvage data, if the drive is not encrypted,  by booting from USB with another OS (Win PE/RE, Linux, etc.). If the drive was encrypted, don't bother. Reinstall Windows 11 (or other OS) -- you might need to remove all partitions first, making the drive all free space..

@Ramhound, how do I "[remove] the device from my MSA"?

By logging into your MSA.

What is "my MSA"? Are you talking about the Microsoft account profile no page?
